# Looking for tab system, jquery/css, which has a ''Show All' option (i.e.) show contents of all other tabs

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

OK, first question on Stackoverflow. I've been searching for a simple tab system which uses jquery/css, there are lots of options but I can't seem to find one which offers a 'Show All' option (i.e.) show the contents of all the other tabs on that level. Can anyone help?

TabA      TabB
Tab1  Tab2   Tab3   Show All Tabs

Where Tab1,Tab2,Tab3,Show All Tabs are nested under TabA, ans similar content for TabB

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question doesn't really fit the criteria of what should be posted here. Questions asking for tools, libraries or other off-site resources are not allowed. Instead, make an attempt at doing this yourself and then come back when you have code that needs troubleshooting.

Comment: Ah, in that case this forum is not what I thought it was, I will look elsewhere.  I don't have the level of skill to code this myself from scratch, I thought if someone could point me to a Jquery/css plugin which offers this functionality I could use it as a starting point, and maybe understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is really what you're looking for - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ay665/4/).

You could just take the contents of the first few divs and permanently put them in the last div. Here, I've just moved them with jQuery.

```
$('.charts').tabs();
$('ul li:nth-child(4)').on('click', function(){
      $('#tabs-4 div').append( $('#tabs-1 .content').text() + '<br />' );
      $('#tabs-4 div').append( $('#tabs-2 .content').text() + '<br />' );
      $('#tabs-4 div').append( $('#tabs-3 .content').text() + '<br />' );

});
```